# Is it possible to convert a mp3 file to m4r with Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Is it possible with Javascript or jQuery to convert mp3, wav, etc. to m4r format?

Comment: Maybe this was a dumb question, but I was just thinking :P

Comment: Well you need a backend to process, you cannot do it using JavaScript.

Comment: Last.fm announced [FLAC.js](http://labs.official.fm/articles/2012/06/15/flac-and-aurora/) the other day.  It looks like [Aurora.js](https://github.com/ofmlabs/aurora.js) and/or [MP3.js](https://github.com/devongovett/mp3.js) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 5):

Let's assume you had a library that can change the format of files.

Let's also assume you only need the application to work on current browsers that implement `FileAPI` or `FileReference` so you can have access to uploaded files (you can't have access to them without `FileAPI` or `FileReference` unless you use `Flash` or `Java Applets` or equivalent technologies).

You wouldn't be able to **write** the output file back to the user because JavaScript is not allowed to access the local filesystem.

Your only solution would become sending the converted file to the server and the server sending it back to you with a force download directive so that the user will be prompted to download the results.

Now back to if there were a library that can the conversion (or even native JavaScript)... I haven't heard of any. It's not impossible to build one but it is impractical and wouldn't run very fast.

### Edit:

Let's not forget ***Node.js***!

It's a backend server that uses Google Chrome's **V8** JavaScript interpretor/compiler. And it runs JavaScript as a backend scripting engine.

You have access to filesystem, databases and everything if you use that (or any other backend system for that matter) and still be using JavaScript. You can use libraries too. Either written in JavaScript or libraries written in other languages that have been linked to interface with Node.js.

### Edit 2:

There is a PC emulator written entirely in JavaScript. It runs binary executables if you want it to. It's called [JSLinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/).

If you're feeling particularly rambunctious you can grab the `ffmpeg` binary executable (compiled with static linking). And embed it into your application code as an uuencoded string then use JSLinux to execute the commands and grab the results.

Comment: Any backend system will have access to the file system; once you're on the backend, you don't need Javascript; you can use any language you want.

Comment: I wasn't implying that Node.js is the only backend system that has access to FS/DB. But i know what you mean I'll alter my wording a bit.

Comment: Thx for all the replies. I will dig more into it with the help i got here :)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is possible doing this on the client using the latest js technologies. A web-worker thread can do the work in the background. At least in Firefox and Chrome it is also possible to read ("upload in memory") and write ("download from memory") files using the new [W3C File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076047/create-a-download-link-from-a-blob-url).

I managed to read files via drag&drop from and within the client [using google's GWT](http://code.google.com/p/lib-gwt-file/) which in the end is plain javascript, so it must also be possible to do it "natively".

Besides that, the conversation algorithm of course has to be implemented in a javascript web worker to avoid blocking the gui. This should be the hardest part, but not impossible, though.

Comment: I didn't know that `FileAPI` can push files (download from memory). I'm reading the spec now to see if I missed this.

Comment: I did this myself based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076047/create-a-download-link-from-a-blob-url - It works!

Comment: All you need to do now is implement the conversion library.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a backend to do this. You may want to look into the [PHPExtension](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) of [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)